# Ist there any easy way to link smoke simulations?

Tags: smoke-simulation, linked-data

I am making an animation that will be reusing a lot of attacks i will make with the smoke simulator. Is there a way to make it (the Smoke simulated attack) in its own file then use it multiple times in other projects?

When I group the Domain and emitter and link it, I don't always get the whole animation, Also i can't seem to move it.
I could just render it then alph overlay it, but i want the 3d Volume of the the smoke in some situations.